# Can anyone solve this Pell equation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pell-type-equations

I have solved the Pell equation  $ p^2 - 95 q^2 =1$ . By looking at  the convergents corresponding to the simple continued fraction of $\sqrt{95}$ I was able to find the fundamental solution $p=39$ and $q=4$ .
I found the five smallest pairs of positive integers $p,q$ that satisfy the above Pell equation. They are : $$\begin{align*} p=39 \quad& q=4 \\
p=3041 \quad&q=312\\
p=237159 \quad& q=24332 \\
p=18495361\quad& q=1897584   \\
p=1442400999 \quad& q=147987220  \end{align*}$$

However  I am having difficulty solving the related Pell equation  $$ p^2 - 95 q^2 =-1 , +1 , -1 , +1 , -1 , +1 , .....$$

The only difference now is that the right hand side of the equation is alternatively $-1$ and $+1$ , instead of just $+1$.  One obvious trivial solution is $p=1$ and $q=0$ , or $p= \sqrt{-1}$ and $q=0$ but these trivial solutions do not count.

I am trying to find the five smallest pairs of positive integers $ p,q$ that satisfy this equation. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Take remainders $\mod 4$, you need $p^2+q^2\equiv3\pmod4$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no solutions to $p^2-95q^2=-1$, because they would imply $p^2\equiv-1\bmod95$, which would imply $p^2\equiv-1\bmod19$, and there are no solutions to $p^2\equiv-1\bmod19$, because there are no solutions to $p^2\equiv-1\bmod n$ for prime $n\equiv-1\bmod4.$

Answer (score 1):

I agree with J W Tanner's answer.  This response is intended to provide alternative analysis.

Given $D \,\in \,\mathbb{Z^+},$ where $D$ is not a perfect square, let 
$[a_0; \overline{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_{n-1}, 2a_0}]$ represent the representation of 
$\sqrt{D}$ as a (simple) continued fraction.

This means that the length of the *period* of this representation is $n.$

Then, it is well settled that if $n$ is even 
then the Diophantine equation $x^2 - Dy^2 = -1$ will have no positive integer solutions.

Comment: Indeed, the continued fraction of $\sqrt{95}$ is $[9;1,2,1,18]$, so the length of the period is even and, therefore, the equation $x^2-95y^2=-1$ has no integral solutions (a reference for this: Theorem 14.3.3 here https://bookstore.ams.org/cdn-1,594,504,037,915/amstext-35/).